# Something like a Scala Option / Optional in R?

Tags: r, scala, option-type

Is there something in R (either a package or base idiom) that is like an Option as found in Scala and other languages (see tag optional for details).  Specifically, I'm looking for the following features some object that can:

- signify the absence of a value but easily
- hold attributes
- return a default value in the face of having no contained value without requiring that the result of the default value be calculated unless it is actually needed

I'm sure there are a lot of other nice characteristics of Options that I haven't fully recognized as I'm relatively new to the idiom.  Any answer that can provide more than the above listed features gets bonus points, especially if the additional features can be described well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried writing a poor substitute using an R6 class (below).  Anything that works better or is more idiomatically aligned with R would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(R6)
Option <- R6Class("Option", 
    public = list(
      initialize = function(value=NULL) {
        self$value <- value
      }
      ,get = function() {
        return(self$value)
      }
      ,set = function(value) {
        self$value <- value
        return(value)
      }
      ,getOrElse = function(...) {
        if(self$isDefined()) {
          return(self$value)
        } else {
          return(eval(...))
        }
      }
      ,isDefined = function() {
        return(!all(is.null(self$value)) && !all(is.na(self$value)))
      }
      , value = NULL
  )
  ,private = list()
  ,active = list()
) #end Option
```

Example:

```
bob <- Option$new()
bob$isDefined() == FALSE
bob$getOrElse("a") == "a"
bob$getOrElse({Sys.sleep(2);"b"})=="b"
bob$set(value = "a")
bob$isDefined() == TRUE
bob$getOrElse({Sys.sleep(2);"b"})=="a"
```